# Google Play App update error

Tags: android, google-play

http://i.imgur.com/vUUiwHi.jpg

Is it because of my libraries?
This is my androidmainifest for my apk:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

<permission
    android:name="PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:name=".PushBotsClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="PACKAGE.MESSAGE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Omega"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_omega" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Alpha"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alpha" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Beta"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_beta" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Delta"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_delta" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Gamma"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gamma" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBMsg" />
    <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBListener" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="PACKAGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.MsgReceiver" />

    <service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
    <service android:name="org.openudid.OpenUDID_service" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".CustomHandler" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Facebook"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_facebook" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Twitter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_twitter" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ScoreWebview"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_score_webview" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewsWebview"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_news_webview" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Instagram"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_instagram" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Welcome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have also included some modules in my project. I have set "app" as release and modules as debug.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvDPv.png

EDIT: build.gradle file for app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "PACKAGE"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 8
    versionName "8"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    //Core
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.0.1'
    //Optional for built-in cards
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.0.1'
    //Optional for RecyclerView
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.0.1'
    //Optional for staggered grid view
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-staggeredgrid:2.0.1'
    //Optional for drag and drop
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-dragdrop:2.0.1'
    //Optional for twoway  (coming soon)
    //compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-twoway:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.0.8'
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.3.0'
    compile files('libs/Pushbots131beta.jar')
    compile 'com.github.xiprox.errorview:library:1.0.0'
    compile project(':PanningViewLibrary')
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.discrollview:library:0.0.2@aar'

}
```

Comment: Can you include your `build.gradle` files? Specifically any listing a `maxSdkVersion`?

Comment: Also, is there any chance you can insert the image inline?  That would be preferable to an external link.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Updated in the OP

Comment: @AriRoth I don't have the required Rep to do that. Im sorry.

Comment: @AriRoth http://i.imgur.com/A27i9CA.jpg

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have 3 projects added as modules for the App. that was the last change

Comment: You could try to run lint. In Android studio : Analyze/Inspect code.

It could help you tracking down potential problem.